# How to use an external css file in a react program

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

So i have created a webpage using react which generates random quotes.
This is the code for the web page:

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Lora:ital@1&display=swap');
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Lato:wght@300&display=swap');
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Lato:wght@300&family=Ubuntu:wght@300&display=swap');

#root{
    position: relative;
}

#quote-box{
  margin: 150px 0 0 -225px;
  padding: 20px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  width: 450px;
  border-radius: 8px;
  z-index: 1;
  background: #fff;
}

#text{
    font-family: 'Lora';
    font-size: 25px;
}

#author{
    font-family: 'Lato';
    font-size: 20px;
    text-align: right;
}

#new-quote{
    font-family: 'Ubuntu';
    color: #fff;
}

.links{
    padding: 5px;
}

.fa{
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html id="root">
    <head>
        <link rel=stylesheet href="QuoteMachine.css"/>
    </head>
    
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/babel-standalone@6.15.0/babel.min.js"></script>
    
    <body>
        <script type="text/babel">
            
            const mainColor= ["#BDB76B", "#228B22", "#00FA9A", "#808000", "#6B8E23", "#008B8B", "#00BFFF", "#000080", "#7B68EE", "#FF00FF", "#4B0082", "#C71585", "#808080", "#2F4F4F", "#DAA520", "#800000", "#D2691E", "#778899", "#40E0D0", "#F0E68C"];
            let index = Math.floor(Math.random()*20);
            
            const QuoteBox = function(props){
                return (
                    <div id="quote-box" className="container-fluid">
                    <p id="text" style={{color: mainColor[props.randomIndex]}}>
                    {props.quotes[props.randomIndex].quote}</p>
                    <p id="author" style={{color: mainColor[props.randomIndex]}}>- {props.quotes[props.randomIndex].author}</p>
                    <button id="new-quote" className="color" onClick={() => {props.onClick()}} className="btn btn-block" style={{background: mainColor[props.randomIndex]}}>New Quote</button><br/>
                    <a id="tweet-quote" href={'https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?text="'+props.quotes[props.randomIndex].quote+'" -'+props.quotes[props.randomIndex].author} className="links" target="_blank">
                    Twitter
                    </a>
                    <a id="facebook" href="https://www.facebook.com/" className="links" target="_blank">
                    Facebook
                    </a>
                    </div>
                );
            }
            
            class Main extends React.Component{
                constructor(props){
                    super(props);
                        this.state = {
                            quotes: [
                                {quote: 'You either die a hero or live long enough to see yourself become  a villain.',
                                author: 'Harvey Dent'},
                                {quote: 'The greatest glory in living lies not in never falling, but in rising every time we fall.', 
                                author: 'Nelson Mandela'},
                                {quote: 'The way to get started is to quit talking and begin doing.', 
                                author: 'Walt Disney'},
                                {quote: "Your time is limited, so don't waste it living someone else's life. Don't be trapped by dogma – which is living with the results of other people's thinking.", 
                                author: 'Steve Jobs'},
                                {quote: 'If life were predictable it would cease to be life, and be without flavor.', 
                                author: 'Eleanor Roosevelt'},
                                {quote: "If you look at what you have in life, you'll always have more. If you look at what you don't have in life, you'll never have enough.", 
                                author: 'Oprah Winfrey'},
                                {quote: "If you set your goals ridiculously high and it's a failure, you will fail above everyone else's success.", 
                                author: 'James Cameron'},
                                {quote: "Life is what happens when you're busy making other plans", 
                                author: 'John Lennon'},
                                {quote: "Spread love everywhere you go. Let no one ever come to you without leaving happier.", 
                                author: 'Mother Teresa'},
                                {quote: "When you reach the end of your rope, tie a knot in it and hang on.", 
                                author: 'Franklin D. Roosevelt'},
                                {quote: "Always remember that you are absolutely unique. Just like everyone else.", 
                                author: 'Margaret Mead'},
                                {quote: "The best and most beautiful things in the world cannot be seen or even touched - they must be felt with the heart.", 
                                author: 'Helen Keller'},
                                {quote: "Whoever is happy will make others happy too.", 
                                author: 'Anne Frank'},
                                {quote: "Tell me and I forget. Teach me and I remember. Involve me and I learn.", 
                                author: 'Benjamin Franklin'},
                                {quote: "In the end, it's not the years in your life that count. It's the life in your years.", 
                                author: 'Abraham Lincoln'},
                                {quote: "Many of life's failures are people who did not realize how close they were to success when they gave up.", 
                                author: 'Thomas A. Edison'},
                                {quote: "Life is never fair, and perhaps it is a good thing for most of us that it is not.", 
                                author: 'Oscar Wilde'},
                                {quote: "Only a life lived for others is a life worthwhile.", 
                                author: 'Albert Einstein'},
                                {quote: "The purpose of our lives is to be happy.", 
                                author: 'Dalai Lama'},
                                {quote: "Love the life you live. Live the life you love.", 
                                author: 'Bob Marley'}
                            ],
                        randomIndex: Math.floor(Math.random()*20)
                    }   
                }
    
    
                generateRandomIndex(){
                    this.setState({randomIndex: Math.floor(Math.random()*20)});
                }
    
    
                render(){
                    return(
                        <div>
                            {/*<Helmet>
                                <style>{'body { background-color:'+ mainColor[this.state.randomIndex]+ '; }'}</style>
                            </Helmet>*/}
            
                        <QuoteBox quotes={this.state.quotes} randomIndex={this.state.randomIndex} onClick={() => {this.generateRandomIndex()}}/>
                        </div>
        )
    }
}

ReactDOM.render(<Main/>, document.getElementById('root'));
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

But for some reason the css styles dont work for the JSX code in the react component. I tried using `import './QuoteMachine.css'` in the JavaScrit part of the code. Still doesnt work.
I had developed the same project using node.js but instead saved it in a separate JavaScript file. It worked fine over there.
This was the following result:

[image]

Can someone tell me how can I achive the same inside an HTML script tag.
This is my first question on StackOverflow so some help would be much appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You could just create a JavaScript Object for your styles and apply them like this:

```
const quoteBoxStyle = {
    margin: "150px 0 0 -225px",
    padding: "20px",
    position: "absolute",
    top: "50%",
    left: "50%",
    width: "450px",
    borderRadius: "8px",
    zIndex: "1",
    background: "#fff",
}
```

and then apply it like this:

```
<div id="quote-box" className="container-fluid" style={quoteBoxStyle}>
```

To actually import it I think you would need an Index.js file.

Comment: Hey thanks! This works too, Although there would be alot if code in the html file itself (since my react component is in the script tag). Anyway thanks

Answer (score 0):

**Create a new file called "Anything.css" and insert some CSS code in it:**

body {

background-color: #282c34;

color: white;

padding: 40px;

font-family: Arial;

text-align: center;
}

**Import the stylesheet in your application:**

import React from 'react';

import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

**import './Anything.css';**  //**Way to import external css files**

class MyHeader extends React.Component {

render() {

```
return (

  <div>

  <h1-tag>Hello Style!</h1-tag>

  <p>Add a little style!.</p>

  </div>
);
```

}
}

ReactDOM.render(, document.getElementById('root'));

Comment: This is how i had written the code before when i had done the project with node.js. Worked fine. But i wanted to know how i could do the same while the react component is inside the <script> tag in the .html file. You cant use export there